# navigator.camera.getPictureでdevicereadyの無限ループ

Tags: android, monaca, camera

公式ドキュメントのサンプルをXperia SO-02E で試しています。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/sampleapp/tips/camera/

サンプルをそのままプレビューしますと、カメラアプリが起動して撮影はできものの、撮影後画像データを読み込んだ後、deviceready してしまうようで、「同期しています」とメッセージが表示された後、一瞬画像が表示され、ふたたび初期画面に戻り、画像はなかったことになってしまいます。無限ループ。

navigator.camera.getPicture 関連で検索しましても、どうもそういう事例はないようなので、so-02eの特有なのかわかりませんが、他にも無限ループしてしまう方いらっしゃいますか？

Answer (score 1):

Nexus7 2013 および Galaxy S4 のMonacaデバッガでも同じことが発生しています。ハイパフォーマンス版でも同様でした。ビルドしたものは問題なく動作するのでデバッガの不具合の可能性が高そうです。

ちなみに手元のiOS環境のデバッガでは不具合は発生していません。

Answer (score 0):

設定を変更したら直りました。

Monacaデバッガーの左サイドメニューの設定
↓
アプリ復帰時にプロジェクトを再起動
↓
off